# Use HttpPost to send multiple data to one URL at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, http-post

I need to send information to an API, but due to memory limitation, I have to split this data into two parts

My question is, how to send this information separately at the same time?

Example:

I tested it this way and only postTo1 is sent

```
result = repository.GetAll();
result2 = repository.GetNames();
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None);
var jsonString2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result2, Formatting.None);

var postTo1 = HttpPostAsync(Url, "[" +jsonString1 + "]");
var postTo2 = HttpPostAsync(Url, "[" +jsonString2 + "]");

static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpPostAsync(string url, string data)
{
  HttpContent content = new StringContent(data);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Why I'm asking is I would almost expect neither request to execute.  var postTo1 and postTo2 are tasks that I don't see you either awaiting or executing.

Comment: a couple questions here, 1. I'm going to second @Hursey question, 2. What are your memory limitations, 3. How big is your data?, 4 Can you give us an example? If we have these I'm sure we can give a great answer.

Comment: @Train 2 - Only 15kb/request,, 3 I'm storing it in a sql query and sending it via push, but it's already at the limit of 15kb.  4 - Edited to improve the example

Comment: @Hursey They do get executed. An async method immediately starts executing the moment you call it. Awaiting them is not technically necessary, but you are usually well advised to to so, because it enables you to know when they are finished, and process the result

Comment: Are you calling it alot? Because 15kb is nothing. I think your httpClient has a leak in it. There is no Using statement and it doesn't look like it's being injected anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're sending it.

If you sent it via a query parameter or the route, just create an object that holds the two strings. You'll be able to get away with a single API call.

If you are already sending it via the body, you'll need to store the data in something like SQL. Return the primary key in the first API call. Then in your second call, pass the primary key in the route. You'll be able to retrieve the first record.

Comment: I'm storing in a sql and pushing it to the api url. Edited the original question to improve the example

Comment: @AllPower - write a second API - something like "MyRoute/Continuation/PreviousPk", where previous Pk is an int. That int should be an API response from the first API.  In your new endpoint, simply retrieve the SQL record you previous stored. You now have both in your API